# Create a E-commerce site builder

Tags: architecture, web, content-management-system

I would like to know what could be the ideas to design an architecture for developing an e-commerce website builder. The idea is to create an online store on the fly which contains payment gateways, dynamic themes, etc. When user registers on the web application then his/her store gets created instantly.
               I am thinking on how to create the individual sites on the server. If anyone has ideas please share. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about a use of subdomains. Every subdomain has his own root map for creating a store, you can set users ftp rights to only the rootmap.